# PyCharm ImportError: No module named googleapiclient

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycharm, google-api-client

I'm new to PyCharm and am trying to build/deploy a simple app to AppEngine.  I've gone to PyCharm-->Preferences, clicked the Project Interpreter, and installed google-api-python-client which includes googleapiclient.  However, when I run this app and load the page, it dies on this line:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
```

with this error:

```
ImportError: No module named googleapiclient
```

I've dropped to PyCharm's CLI interpreter and run the same command where it runs fine, only when running as web app does it fail.

Have looked through the other folks having the same problem, and all the solutions talk about installing the package in the project interpreter, which I've already done, but it's still failing.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the client library's [Installation instructions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#installation):

> For information on installing the source for the library into your App
>   Engine project, see the [App Engine specific installation
>   instructions](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine).

Which states:

> Because the Python client libraries are not installed in the [App
>   Engine Python runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/), they must be [vendored into
>   your application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) just like third-party libraries.

The role of these instructions is to make the app itself self-contained and keep the dev server happy - they do not know (and should not need to know) how to read pycharm configs to run the code.

Comment: Thanks, your link to vendor in the library helped.  I knew the libraries needed to be uploaded but wasn't quite sure how.  This did it :)